# how to use Hashicorp Vault PKI backend to generate dynamic certificates for minions

Tags: salt-stack, hashicorp-vault

We are planning on moving away In our dev environment, we are in a situation where we need to issue certificates to salt minion clients using Vault.

Current salt module supports sending plain kv values to minions but nothing except that. Salt don't even support any auth methods except default tokens while we are looking to implement Vault's AppRole for authentication,
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2017.7/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.vault.html

we have so far followed this guide to setup environment https://backbeat.tech/blog/secure-servers-with-saltstack-and-vault-part-1 but it isn't as of much help since our development has different requirements. I want to ask if there is any implementation of Vault + Salt which would allow us issue private certificates to salt minions using hashicorp vault and use more sophisticated way of authentication instead of just token?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was looking into setting something similar with Vault + Salt, we also need to deploy certs + have a CA. 

Have you tried the x509 setup? It works pretty nicely (even though it uses an old m2crypto lib)

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.x509.html

Answer (score 0):

> use more sophisticated way of authentication instead of just token?

There is `AppRole` support available on [v2018.11 branch](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/v2018.11/salt/modules/vault.py). You can add it in your salt as a new module instead of overwriting original vault module.

> I want to ask if there is any implementation of Vault + Salt which
>   would allow us issue private certificates to salt minions using
>   hashicorp vault

You can use [vault module for salt-stack](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.vault.html) to create your PKI. It allows you to write to vault PKI backend using `vault.write_secret` execution module. Something like,

```
salt-call vault.write_secret "<pki_backend_name>/issue/<role_name>" common_name="<___>" ttl="100h" format="pem"
```

or from a state,

```
{% set generate_certificate = salt['vault'].write_secret("<pki_backend_name>/issue/<role_name>", common_name="<___>", ttl="100h", format="pem") %}
```

I have written this [guide on how you can use vault to generate PKI](https://medium.com/@sufiyanghori/guide-using-hashicorp-vault-to-manage-pki-and-issue-certificates-e1981e7574e), it can come handy.

Hope it helps.